# A better way of evaluating two objects

Tags: c#, list

I'm struggling to find a better way of evaluating two objects that may or may not be a list of strings.

I feel that there must be a better way of doing the below. Does anyone have some advice that can help me please?

I'm getting the objects from a web service, so there is no way of knowing beforehand what type of objects they are.

```
private bool EvaluateDataLists(object dataLeft, object dataRight)
{
    bool isDataLeftList = dataLeft is List<string>;
    bool isDataRightList = dataRight is List<string>;

    if (isDataLeftList && !isDataRightList)
    {
        foreach (var entry in dataLeft as List<string>)
        {
            if (Expression.Evaluate(entry, dataRight.ToString(), valueOperator))
                return true;
        }
    }
    else if (!isDataLeftList && isDataRightList)
    {
        foreach (var entry in dataRight as List<string>)
        {
            if (Expression.Evaluate(dataLeft.ToString(), entry, valueOperator))
                return true;
        }
    }
    else if (isDataLeftList && isDataRightList)
    {
        foreach (var leftEntry in dataLeft as List<string>)
        {
            foreach (var rightEntry in dataRight as List<string>)
            {
                if (Expression.Evaluate(leftEntry, rightEntry, valueOperator))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: One really obvious way to simplify the thing is to *ensure* that both objects are in fact lists, and if they're not, *make* them lists. A singleton value can simply be represented as a one-element list.

Comment: "I'm getting the objects from a web service, so there is no way of knowing beforehand what type of objects they are." Unless your web service serializes raw .NET code (which is improbable), the results are just what your deserialization code makes of them. (And even if it is most convenient to have it spit out `object`s that you have to check for types, this *still* does not preclude the possibility of shunting the type checks and making the typing more uniform before you start evaluating things.)

Comment: In addition to ensuring that they are both lists, you can also ensure what they contain. We want as much of our code as possible to be strongly typed. If we deal with a service or library that returns untyped data we can validate it and then cast or map it to something strongly typed as soon as possible. That way the part of our code that deals with untyped data is limited, and that untyped data doesn't leak out into the rest of our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question/code correctly does this solve your problem or help?

```cs
private bool EvaluateDataLists(object dataLeft, object dataRight)
{
    List<string> left = (dataLeft is List<string>) ? dataLeft as List<string> : new List<string> { dataLeft.ToString() };
    List<string> right = (dataRight is List<string>) ? dataRight as List<string> : new List<string> { dataRight.ToString() };

    foreach (string item in left)
    {
        if (right.Where(r => Expression.Evaluate(item, r, valueOperator)).Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If so, I would probably refactor the two halves of the method into two separate methods - one to ensure you have lists of strings, and a second do iterate and compare

Comment: I would use .Exists rather than .Where... Count > 0

Comment: Thanks for you answer Toby. This isn't exactly what I want, but it's my fault for not explaining properly. So these two objects can either be a string or a list of strings. If one of these objects is a list of strings, then I want to iterate through all of those strings and compare each one of them to the other object(which might be a string or a list of strings).

Comment: The value operator could be anything from Equals, LessThan, GreaterThan etc. With this it compares the two string values.

Comment: @CareTaker22 - I'm afraid that I'm slightly more confused now, how can you perform those operators on strings? Does the code I posted does not perform the same functionality as the code in your question?

Comment: In the Expression.Evaluate method, it parses it to double. And I'm very sorry for not reading your code extensively. It actually does what I need it to do! Thank you.

Comment: I missed the part where you added the single string value to a list of strings.

Comment: @CareTaker22 - no worries, happy to help :)